# issue with path resolved on complex app nestjs based

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, nestjs

I building a boildplate for nestjs and microservices (still work in progress)

now i got an issue that i try to run the app or run the test and it give me this [image]

the code located [github link](https://github.com/Sivanwol/projectShowcase/tree/master/backend)
the issue that on tsconfig.json i added paths

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/apps",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@frontapi/*": ["./apps/front-api/src/*"],
      "@config/*": ["./apps/config-server/src/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["./apps/entities-server/src/*"],
      "@devops/*": ["./apps/devops-mcu/src/*"],
      "@tasks/*": ["./apps/task-que-handler/src/*"],
      "@logicBus/*": ["./apps/logic-bus/src/*"],
      "@common/*": ["./apps/common/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

and i run the package json two of the commands for testing:
"start:frontapi": "npm run start:frontapi:env && tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register --inspect-brk=5858 dist/front-api/src/main.js\"",

and
"test:e2e": "npm run clean&&tsc -p tsconfig.build.json && jest --config ./apps/front-api/test/jest-e2e.json",

and both give me that it dont located @common/config/configuration 
and i have no idea what i have missing here and help with this one

Edit there is file called jest-e2e.json this his content

```js
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@frontapi/(.*)$": "./apps/front-api/src/$1",
    "^@config/(.*)$": "./apps/config-server/src/$1",
    "^@entities/(.*)$": "./apps/entities-server/src/$1",
    "^@devops/(.*)$": "./apps/devops-mcu/src/$1",
    "^@tasks/(.*)$": "./apps/task-que-handler/src/$1",
    "^@logicBus/(.*)$": "./apps/logic-bus/src/$1",
    "^@common/(.*)$": "./apps/common/$1"
  }
}
```

please let me know if i missing something here or you missing something will do my best to provide

Comment: Do you have your paths mapped in your `jest.e2e.json` config?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yap just edit the post show it content

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

After taking a look at your project structure, I have some suggestions/observations. I will focus on apps/front-api.

There you have the jest.e2e.json file inside the test directory

```json
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  ...,
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@frontapi/(.*)$": "./apps/front-api/src/$1",
    "^@config/(.*)$": "./apps/config-server/src/$1",
    "^@entities/(.*)$": "./apps/entities-server/src/$1",
    "^@devops/(.*)$": "./apps/devops-mcu/src/$1",
    "^@tasks/(.*)$": "./apps/task-que-handler/src/$1",
    "^@logicBus/(.*)$": "./apps/logic-bus/src/$1",
    "^@common/(.*)$": "./apps/common/$1"
  }
}
```

I'd like to point out that the `rootDir: '.'` makes reference to the directory the file is in, so in this case rootDir value will be `/path/to/your/projectShowCase/backend/apps/front-api/test`.

The important thing is that you can use relative paths in the moduleNameMapper. For instance:

```json
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@frontapi/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../src/$1",
    "^@config/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../../config-server/src/$1",
    ...,
    "^@common/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../../common/$1"
  }
```

You just need to map each dependency to its specific path